# Project is not created in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to run my plugin project as an application using handler class:

```
@Override
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
    IWorkbenchWindow window =
            HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);
    MessageDialog.openInformation(
        window.getShell(), "MenuEclipseArticle Plug-in",
        "Hello, Eclipse world");
    CreateProject create=new CreateProject();
    IPath  projectLocation =  new Path("C:/Users/monika.sharma/Desktop/software");
    String projectName = "myProject1234";
    create.createProject(projectLocation, projectName);

    return null;
}
```

I have created a **createProject** Java class to creete a project with **src** and **bin** folder..

```
public class CreateProject {

    static boolean createAtExternalLocation = false;
     static IPath projectLocation=null;
     private IProject project;
     private IJavaProject javaProject;

    public void createProject(IPath projectLocation,String projectName)
    {
        IProgressMonitor progressMonitor = new NullProgressMonitor();
    IProject project =ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject(projectName);
    IProjectDescription description =ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().newProjectDescription(project .getName());
    description.setLocation(projectLocation);

    try {
        project.create(description, progressMonitor);
    } catch (CoreException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        project.open(progressMonitor);
    } catch (CoreException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     try {
        setJavaNature();
    } catch (CoreException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     // Add JRE
     try {
        addDefaultJRE(progressMonitor);
    } catch (JavaModelException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     // Create the bin folder
     try {
        createBinFolder();
    } catch (CoreException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     // Create a source folder
     try {
        IPackageFragmentRoot src = createSourceFolder("src");
    } catch (CoreException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    public void setJavaNature() throws CoreException {
         // Get the description of the project
         IProjectDescription description = project.getDescription();
         // Change the description with NATURE_ID of JavaCore
         description.setNatureIds(new String[] {JavaCore.NATURE_ID});
         // Set the description back to the project
         project.setDescription(
             description, null);
    }
    public void addDefaultJRE(IProgressMonitor progressMonitor) throws JavaModelException {
         // Create an empty class path entry array for the project
         javaProject.setRawClasspath(
             new IClasspathEntry[0], progressMonitor);
         // Get it - the old entries
         IClasspathEntry[] oldEntries = javaProject.getRawClasspath();
         // Increase 1 for the size of the new entry array.
         IClasspathEntry[] newEntries = new IClasspathEntry[oldEntries.length + 1];
         // Copy the old entries to new entry array.
         System.arraycopy(
             oldEntries, 0, newEntries, 0, oldEntries.length);
         // Set the new element to the default JRE of the system.
         newEntries[oldEntries.length] = JavaRuntime.getDefaultJREContainerEntry();
         // Set back entry paths to the project
         javaProject.setRawClasspath(
             newEntries, progressMonitor);
    }
    public IFolder createBinFolder() throws CoreException {
         // Get the folder with the name bin
         IFolder binFolder = project.getFolder("bin");
         // Create this folder. if the first parameter is false, it does not
         // forced to override the folder
         binFolder.create(
             false, true, null);
         // Get the path of the bin folder
         IPath outputLocation = binFolder.getFullPath();
         // Set that path as the output location of the project
         javaProject.setOutputLocation(
             outputLocation, null);
         return binFolder;
    }
    public IPackageFragmentRoot createSourceFolder(String srcName) throws CoreException {
         // Get the folder with srcName name. It may be not exist
         IFolder folder = project.getFolder(srcName);
         // Create a real folder. In the case you want to force override the
         // folder,
         // set the first parameter as true
         folder.create(
             false, true, null);
         // Get the source folder as root package
         IPackageFragmentRoot root = javaProject.getPackageFragmentRoot(folder);
         // Do the samething on the addDefaultJRE method
         IClasspathEntry[] oldEntries = javaProject.getRawClasspath();
         IClasspathEntry[] newEntries = new IClasspathEntry[oldEntries.length + 1];
         System.arraycopy(
             oldEntries, 0, newEntries, 0, oldEntries.length);
         // Add a new source folder as a new entry for class paths
         newEntries[oldEntries.length] = JavaCore.newSourceEntry(root.getPath());
         // Set back entry paths to the project
         javaProject.setRawClasspath(
             newEntries, null);
         return root;
    }
```

When I run MANIFEST.MF file using 'Run as Eclipse Application' only Eclipse is opened but the project is not created.

Comment: How are you running the handler? You will need a menu item or tool bar button to run this code.

Comment: I am running using run as eclipse application.i have added org.eclipes.ui.menus. can you tell me about menu item or tool bar button ?

Comment: Run as Eclipse application just starts a new Eclipse with a new workspace containing your plugin. It does not run the handler. Your handler will only run when you invoke it using something like the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point.

Comment: Read something like [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommands/article.html)

Answer (score 1):

'Run as Eclipse Application' just starts a new Eclipse which includes your plugin. The new Eclipse uses a separate workspace. Look in the 'Eclipse Applications' section of the 'Run > Run Configurations' dialog for details.

This does not call your handler code. A handler is only run when it called from something like a menu item or a tool bar button. The handler must be declared using the `org.eclipse.ui.handlers` extension point. For more details on handlers read something like [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommands/article.html).